# How Do I Pass on an Array of Objects using "forEach" Function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a `Card` object that I have created in `Card.js`

```
 (const Card = (playerImage, name, position))
```

Every `Card` is built by the data that created in `Players.js`.

In `Index.js` file I tried to use `forEach` function in order to pass over each index in the array and create a `Card`.

The message error is:

> 'player' is not defined

(Using `forEach` in order to get better, I know it's not needed)

Thanks :)

Players.js:

```
export const players = [
    {
        image = "https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/01/09/15470342504519.jpg",
        name = 'Keylor Navas',
        position = "GK"
    },
    {
        image = "https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/01/09/15470342504519.jpg",
        name = 'Sergio Ramos',
        position = "CB"
    }
]
```

Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <div>
        players.forEach(player, index) => {
            <Card img = {player.image} name = {player.name} position = {player.position}/>
        });
    </div>),
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: 1. you need to use `map()` instead of `forEach()` 2. You need to return the `<Card />` from the function.

Comment: Also, you have a missing opening parenthesis before `player`. Should be `players.map((player, index) => (<Card ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the index.

```
ReactDOM.render((
<div>
    {players.map((user, i) => {
        return ( 
           <Card 
                 key={i} 
                 img={players[i].image} 
                 name={players[i].name} 
                 position={players[i].position}
           /> 
        )
     });
    }
</div>),
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code

Instead of

`players.forEach(player, index)`

Your code should be

`players.forEach((player, index)`

You are missing a `(`

Comment: This is already mentioned in a comment. Furthermore, SO has a built-in feature where one "vote/flag to close as a typographical error", and as those aren't real coding issues and are useless to future users, we don't post answer for them. So please delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use map instead of forEach

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <div>
    {players.map((player, index) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={index} // if you objec has a Id field use it instead //of map index 
          img={player.img}
          name={player.name}
          position={player.position}
        />
      )
    });
    }
  </div>),
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the map iterator instead of foreach. 
Also, please validate the data in your Players.js file the data is not valid JSON Data. The Data should be proper JSON Data, otherwise you would get the error. see the following corrected data.

```
export const players =[
    {
        image : "https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/01/09/15470342504519.jpg",
        name : 'Keylor Navas',
        position : "GK"
    },
    {
        image : "https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/01/09/15470342504519.jpg",
        name : 'Sergio Ramos',
        position : "CB"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# players.js
const players = [
  {
      image: "https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/01/09/15470342504519.jpg",
      name: 'Keylor Navas',
      position: "GK"
  },
  {
      image: "https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/01/09/15470342504519.jpg",
      name: 'Sergio Ramos',
      position:"CB"
  }
]
export players

# index.js
const myList = players.forEach( (player, index) => {
          <Card key={index} img={player.image} name={player.name} position={player.position}/>
      })

ReactDOM.render(<div>{myList}</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```